# Get CruiseControl.Net to display Java output

Tags: java, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to get my CruiseControl.Net server to execute a Java app and display System.out on the website and emails.

So far, it seems to be displaying only System.err on the emails, and none of the output on the website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the executable task which is similar to the command line console. Please take a look [here](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task).